# change background of div using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to change background of a div, i have write below code but it not change background

Code is:

```
$('#Chngclr').click(function(){
        var color = $('#color').val();
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addcolor.php",
                data: 'value='+color,
                success: function(msg){
                //alert(msg);
                //$("#first").hide();
                $('#step2').html(msg);
                $('#outer').css('background-color:'+ msg);
                }
            });
        });
```

Help me

Comment: what did alert(msg); generate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i remember parameters for **css** function is JSON like

```
$('#outer').css({ "background-color", msg });
```

Or

Just as parameters if you change only one property

```
$('#outer').css('background-color', msg)
```